# Angular - Using a component across multiple modules

Tags: angular, angular-module

**What I'm using**

- Angular

**What I'm trying to do**

- I have a loading component I want to reuse across multiple modules

**What I've done**

- I've created a new module called 'loading-overlay'
- Inside this module I export the overlay component
- I add this module to app.module
- When adding the component to multiple modules I receive the following error:

> Type LoadingOverlayComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: LoadingOverlayModule and ProjectsModule! Please consider moving LoadingOverlayComponent to a higher module that imports LoadingOverlayModule and ProjectsModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoadingOverlayComponent then import that NgModule in LoadingOverlayModule and ProjectsModule.

- I've tried removing it from app.module and importing it into the other modules I need without much luck. I must be missing some obvious.

**Overlay Module**

```js
// Modules
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Components
import { LoadingOverlayComponent } from './loading-overlay.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoadingOverlayComponent,
  ],

  imports: [

  ],

  exports: [
    LoadingOverlayComponent
  ],

  providers: [ ],

})

export class LoadingOverlayModule { }
```

**App Module**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Routing
import { AppRouting } from './routing/app-routing';

// Modules
import { ProjectsModule } from './projects/projects.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { LoadingOverlayModule } from './loading-overlay/loading-overlay.module';


// Services / Providers
import { AuthService } from './user/auth.service'





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRouting,
    LoadingOverlayModule  
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Project Module**

```js
// Modules
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoadingOverlayModule } from '../loading-overlay/loading-overlay.module';

import { LoadingOverlayComponent } from '../loading-overlay/loading-overlay.component';






@NgModule({
  declarations: [

    LoadingOverlayComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,

    LoadingOverlayModule
  ],

  providers: [ ],

})

export class ProjectsModule { }
```

Any help pointing out what I've stupidly missed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do as the error says? Remove `LoadingOverlayComponent` from `ProjectsModule `?

Comment: Bugger. That's my bad. I tried a bunch of things so quickly I forgot to remove that. However, now that's removed I get the following: "'app-loading-overlay' is not a known element:  If 'app-loading-overlay' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module." - This is probably why i ended up adding the component in the module too.

Comment: What's the relation between `ProjectsModule` and `AppModule`? Are you using it in any other module except these 2?

Comment: Hi Echonax - App Module is importing every module I have and need including ProjectsModule. ProjectModule just contains modules and components to display a list of projects (components, angular material modules etc)

Comment: You need to import `LoadingOverlayModule` in every module where you are using any of its directives. Maybe you missed to import it somewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove :

`LoadingOverlayModule` from `AppModule`

`LoadingOverlayComponent` from `ProjectsModule`

And :

`import` `LoadingOverlayModule` Where its required

Comment: Thanks all. Turns out that did work. Someone else happened to have added the snippet to another HTML component which I wasn't aware of and it didn't throw it up in the error! Thanks for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MegaTron, Happens sometime, now you are smarter :)

Comment: I need more explanation. can you provide some more detail?  Like I want to use that loading component in login while checking authentication, or other modules where I need to use that component so where I need to import ? on component or module or where?

Answer (score 8):

**LoadingOverlayModule** is shared module. It has its own component. Now to use its component you need to import **LoadingOverlayModule** into Project module. Remove **LoadingOverlayComponent** from project module's declarations.

You will need another component (say *ProjectComponent*) for Project Module declaration. As shared module is imported into you project module you can directly use overlay component in *ProjectComponent* template, using selector. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

## General answer

For those of you looking for a generalized answer similar to me:

1. Remove already created component from appmodule
2. Create new module e.g. `SharedModule`
3. Import and export already created component
4. Import module into module where component is already required

###### Thats it!

---

### Longer explanation

I have a few `components`i want to share across the entire project. I created a new module called `ComponentsModule` which looks like this:

```js
     @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        BannerComponent,
        ImageAndTextComponent,
        InfoAndImageComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      exports: [
        BannerComponent,
        
      ]
    })
    export class ComponentsModule { }
```

I want to use `BannerComponent` in `UtviklingComponent` which is a child of `UtviklingModule`. You can see the code for `UtviklingModule` below

```js
   @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        UtviklingComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          {path: 'utvikling', component: UtviklingComponent,data: {animation: "UtviklingPage"}},
        ])
      ]
    })
    export class UtviklingModule { }
```