# Angular 7- How can i Use one component with diffrent modules

Tags: angular, angular7

i have a project that is lazy loaded, it has 2 modules view.module.ts and view2.modules.ts other than module.ts. i want to use a component called editform.component.ts in both modules. is it possible??

Comment: Yes. It should be declared and exported in a shared module, and the two lazy-loaded modules should import this shared module.

Comment: Are you looking for this? [Angular - Using a component across multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305169/angular-using-a-component-across-multiple-modules)

Comment: its pretty simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use component you can use a shared module.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SomeModule
     ],
    declarations: [
         SharedComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        SharedComponent
    ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

Now inside that shared module you can add the component that you want to share. Do not forget to put them into exports.

Now add this module into your `app.module.ts`

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module;

@NgModule({
    imports: [ SharedModule],
     ...
})
```

Now you can use the shared component via app.module.ts. Hope this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a component that imported in a different module. You should have shared component with his sharedModule, then import that module to your module. And also add that component in your sharedModule's "exports" section.